# How to minimize locking yet maintaining the database related operation is atomic

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ftp

I have a general question about how to minimize database locking yet guarantee the operation is atomic. My case specifically relates to C# / SQL Server but this is probably a language agnostic issue.

We have to periodically write sales earning to a file and send it to another server via FTP. Here's our current process:

- Get unprocessed total sales from Sales Table in last hour
- Write total sales / earnings / misc info to files
- Begin DB Transaction
- Update Sales Table indicating the sales have been processed
- Send files to FTP
- Commit Transaction

The problem is, we send a large number of files to FTP server and this process takes quite a while. This has been causing some locking issues, where our customers cannot register or modify sales. However, if FTP transfer or database update fails for whatever reason, we need to rollback the db operation and delete any previously sent files.

What's a recommended way to guarantee that the operation is atomic yet minimize locking?

Comment: Why is it necessary to send files to FTP *before* comitting the transaction? (*Is* it necessary, or could you do "begin;update;commit;ftp"?)

Comment: If any errors occur while sending FTP files, the operation has to be rolled back to initial state.

Comment: Okay, then the problem cannot be solved at this level of abstraction: the issue is not with database locking, but with the underlying business logic. In other words: why FTP? What happens with the files on the other side (at the FTP server)? Would it help to just put the files into a local transfer queue and have another process shuttle them to the FTP server?

Comment: @Piskvor My hunch was also that this problem is fundamentally impossible to solve at this level, but just wanted to venture for any clever ideas. Here's the background: we're sending sales data to a service designed by SAP. I don't actually know why FTP was chosen as a medium for transferring data (The previous maintainer of the project has long left the company), but it is what it is and I have to deal with it. The files on the other end is collected by SAP's automated service and inserted into their server's database.

Comment: @Piskvor There's a designated timeslot which the files MUST be sent by (operation is extremely sensitive on when sales were finalized on our end and registered on SAP), so implementing job queue for FTP files alone would be impossible in my eyes.

Comment: Perhaps cooperating with the other end would work? E.g. begin transaction-update-tell SAP "I'm about to send you these data via FTP"-commit-send via FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add more meaning to the status field of the Sales table:

- Not Processed
- ***Processing***
- Processed

This way you don't have to lock the rows (and pages in MS SQL Server) for a whole duration required to send files over FTP. You just lock the relevant records while selecting them, then you update the status to "Processing" and finally you release the lock.

After FTP job finishes you update the relevant records as "Processed".

Also you should develop a scheduled process to check if FTP job has failed or not. Status of the records which belong to failed FTP processes should be updated to "Not Processed" again.

Edit: You may find the SQL script below

```
begin tran

declare @toBeProcessed table(saleid int);

insert into @tobeProcessed
select saleid
from Sales (rowlock) 
where status = 'NotProcessed'

update Sales
set status = 'Processing'
where saleid in (select saleid from @toBeProcessed)

commit

select * from @toBeProcessed
```

Comment: I like this idea, but how do I manually designate which rows to lock?